# How can I disable the "Send Message?" warning with emails having blank subjects/bodies?

Tags: email, alerts

I frequently email attached files from my phone to myself. I am not worried about cataloging or anything, so most emails have blank subjects and blank bodies. However, whenever I send the email, the "Send Message?" warning message asking, for the hundredth time, "Send this message without text in the subject?"

Although yes, this might be a life-saver for others here or there, it is more of an annoyance for me and my usage; so how do I disable the error? (Yes, I am aware of other apps to make files accessible by cloud, but email is seems fastest and most universal for on-demand stuff.)

[2.2.2][FRG83G]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears it's not possible, even on gmail.com, according to [this answer](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=65dba956af5abf0c).  Gmail does understand the "[EOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_Message)" tag at the end of the subject and will not prompt you about having an empty message body if that exists anywhere in the subject (even if it's the only thing in the subject).

Comment: Nice substitute with the EOM idea

Answer (score 0):

Use a different email app that doesn't do it or allows you to shut it off.

Comment: Yes. I'm fine with Gmail though, any chance you know how to disable the error?

Comment: If there was a way, I would have suggested it :) Presumably you could hack the app, but that would be slightly on the difficult side.